# Query for getting data from two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables `QUESTIONS` and `STUDENT_ANSWER`. Each table has columns `PAPER_ID` and `QUESTION_NO`, `STUDENT_ANSWER` has a column `STUDENT_ID`, if a student submit the paper then in `STUDENT_ANSWER` table stores the `STUDENT_ID`, `QUESTION_NO`, `STUDENT_ANSWER` and `PAPER_ID`.

I want `Answer` from `QUESTIONS` table which stores correct answers where `PAPER_ID` is `'Basic Computer'` and `Answers` from table `STUDENT_ANSWER` which store student answer where `PAPER_ID` is `'Basic Computer`' and `STUDENT_ID` is `1`

```
select 
    q.answer, s.student_ans 
from 
    questions q, student_answer s 
where 
    s.student_id = 1 
    and q.paper_id = 'Basic Computer'
    and s.paper_id = 'Basic Computer';
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: So what's the problem with your current approach?

Comment: And a question.  A question should have a question in it as well.  It is not clear what your issue is.

Comment: Sounds like your learning SQL, especially if that's the case, you should learn to use explicit `join` syntax. Comma separated join style is out of date since 1992!

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.student_id,
       q.paper_id,
       q.question_no,
       q.answer, 
       s.student_answer
  from questions      q, 
       student_answer s 
 where s.student_id  = 1 
   and q.paper_id    = 'Basic Computer'
   and s.paper_id    = q.paper_id
   and s.QUESTION_NO = q.QUESTION_NO

-- result
student_id | paper_id       | question_no | answer | student_answer
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | Basic Computer | 1           | red    | blue
1          | Basic Computer | 2           | green  | yellow
1          | Baisc Computer | 3           | blue   | brown
```

Is that what you're looking for?